# Import Only Necessary CSV Columns In IDL

Tags: python, arrays, csv, idl-programming-language

I am struggling to find a function in IDL that will replicate something I have done in Python with Pandas. I am new to IDL and there is next to nothing resource wise that I can find.

In Python, I use the following:

```
pd.read_csv('<csv filepath>', usecols=[n])
```

The usecols part will only pull in the columns of a CSV I would like in my data frame. Is there a way to do this in IDL?

I hope this makes sense - my first post here!

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the "idl" tag is for Interface Definition Language. Interactive Data Language is "idl-programming-language".

Comment: Thank you, will get that changed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `READ_CSV` routine that can read CSV files, but it does not have a way to pull out specific columns. It will give you a structure with one field for each column of the CSV file — so you could just grab the column you need from the structure and throwing away the rest of the structure. Something like:

```
csv = read_csv('somefile.csv')
col_n = csv.(n)
```

Comment: I hadn't realised that IDL made a structure of individual, separated columns like it does until this morning. I was also unaware I could use csv.(n). Very helpful, thank you!